# Am I an English citizen by descent?

Tags: united-kingdom

My grandfather was born in Cyprus in 1919 and  I wonder if I am an English citizen by descend.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, for several reasons:

1. With very few exceptions, any British nationality status that was solely as a result of connection to a former colony (and not to the UK or a current British territory) was lost when that former colony became independent or was ceded. This includes Cyprus, and people who acquired Cypriot citizenship upon independence, which includes anyone born in Cyprus, lost Citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies status. However, if one was born in the two British Sovereign Base Areas, one could potentially have retained CUKC status and now be a British Overseas Territories Citizen (though still not full British citizen).
2. British nationality generally only extends to one generation born abroad, i.e. a child born abroad only gets British nationality status of the parent if the parent was British "otherwise than by descent". Since you mentioned it was your grandfather who was born in Cyprus, I assume that your parent and you were not born in Cyprus or another British territory, which would generally mean you couldn't have gotten your grandparent's British status, even if it was not lost upon the independence of Cyprus.

Answer (score 1):

Your grandfather is completely irrelevant. You are usually British Citizen by descent if one of your parents is British Citizen not by descent, and you were born outside the UK. You are usually a British Citizen not by descent if one of your parents is a British Citizen (by descent or not) and you were born in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

You might visit [this UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen), which poses questions for your response, in order to answer the "Am I a British citizen?" query. (The website presents a definitive answer for those born after 1983, but not for those born before 1983.)

Comment: I find that tool useless, since for people born before 1983 it eventually asks "Were you a UK and Colonies citizen on 31 December 1982 with right of abode in the UK?"

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks. I've edited the answer to reflect that the site is useful only for a limited set of people.

Answer (score 0):

legitimate descent from a CUKC father for children born elsewhere. Only the first generation acquired British nationality automatically. Second and subsequent generations could do so only if born outside the Commonwealth (or Ireland) and registered within 12 months of birth or if the father was in Crown Service.
incorporation of territory (no persons ever acquired CUKC this way from 1949)